# Similar matrices with same invertible matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices, then
$B = P^{-1}AP$ and $A = P^{-1}BP$ for some invertible matrix $P$. True or false.

All I know is if $A, B$ and $C$ are similar matrices then there is equivalence relation within them. Can someone please look into this and let me know whether is it true or false?. If is it true, then why and if false, provide me the justification.

Comment: What does “there is equivalence relation within them” mean?

Comment: I meant Suppose A, B and C are square matrices of size n. Then, A is similar to A (Reflexive), If A is similar to B, then B is similar to A(Symmetric), and It is transitive too. However, I am unable to understand whether this is even relevant with what has been asked in the question.

Comment: It is not relevant.

Comment: Ok. Then how to approach to this question? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The formula you have given is usually how similar matrices are defined, so it is true. There is other criteria for similar matrices, such as equal determinants and equal traces. So if you use the definition given in your question to check if the criteria hold that will work

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with the other criteria to check for that. However, when I am pondering over that, I am thinking, how the same invertible matrix used in both cases. Means, If one can be P in the first case, then in the second case there can be another invertible matrix Q of size n. To be conclusive, if the matrixes are similar then,  a unique P exists which satisfies both the above equations.  Am I correct?

Comment: $P$ wouldn't necessarily be unique, as two matrices with real entries can have a complex matrix which makes them similar and a real matrix which also makes them similar.

Comment: If $B=P^{-1}AP$ then $A=PBP^{-1}$.  You claim $A=P^{-1}BP$.  This is not obvious and I strongly suspect it is false, although finding a specific counterexample may be tricky.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am confused over here. I agree with you. Please suggest.

Comment: @Scosh_lr No. Equal determinants and traces is not a criteria. A trivial example is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1& -1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ and the zero matrix. They have the same determinant and the same trace but are not similar.

Comment: @mouthetics I didn't mean that equal trace implies similarity, rather the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the problem statement says that $B=P^{-1}AP$ and $A=P^{-1}BP$ --- rather than $A=PBP^{-1}$. As it stands, the statement is false.

Consider the case where $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,3)$ and $B=S^{-1}AS$, where $S=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0}$. By construction, the two matrices are similar to each other. Recall that diagonal matrices with distinct diagonal entries only commute with diagonal matrices. If $B=P^{-1}AP$ for some matrix invertible $P$, then $(PS^{-1})A=A(PS^{-1})$. Therefore $PS^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix, meaning that
$$
P=\pmatrix{0&a&0\\ 0&0&b\\ c&0&0} \text{ for some } a,b,c\ne0.\tag{1}
$$
Now, if we also have $A=P^{-1}BP$, then $A=P^{-1}BP=P^{-1}(P^{-1}AP)P=P^{-2}AP^2$. Therefore $P^2A=AP^2$, i.e. $P^2$ is a diagonal matrix. Yet this is not possible for any $P$ in the form of $(1)$.

Comment: Well, this is pretty strange because, $B = S^{-1}AS = \pmatrix{1&-1\\ 0&2}$. And we can easily see that $S^{-1}BS = A$. Therefore this is not a counterexample.

Comment: @EulerPythagoras Oops, I've picked a wrong $S$ (with $S^2=I$!!!). It should be easy to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

If $A = P^{-1}BP$ and $B = P^{-1}BP$ then also $B = PBP^{-1}$ and hence $P^2B = BP^2$.

Take $P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$.

We have

$$P^2B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 8 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$BP^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$
so they are not equal.